# How to use aiplatformpb GenerateContentRequest in Go (getting a 404)?

Tags: go, google-ai-platform

I'm getting the following error when trying to use Gemini Pro via Go (1.22.1) and the aiplatform (1.64) package:

> rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 404 (Not Found); transport: received unexpected content-type "text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Here's my Golang code:

```golang
func googleGemini() string {
    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := aiplatform.NewPredictionClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("[googleGemini] ERROR! %v", err)
        return ""
    }

    var parts []*aiplatformpb.Part
    parts = append(parts, &aiplatformpb.Part{
        Data: &aiplatformpb.Part_Text{
            Text: "Hello!",
        },
    })

    content := &aiplatformpb.Content{
        Role:  "user",
        Parts: parts,
    }
    // endpoint := "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
    model := "gemini-1.0-pro-001"
    location := "us-central1"
    contentRequest := aiplatformpb.GenerateContentRequest{
        Model: fmt.Sprintf(
            "projects/%s/locations/%s/publishers/google/models/%s",
            PROJECT_ID(), location, model),
        Contents: []*aiplatformpb.Content{content},
    }

    resp, err := client.GenerateContent(ctx, &contentRequest)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("[googleGemini] ERROR! %v", err)
        return ""
    }

    return resp.Candidates[0].Content.Parts[0].GetText()
}
```

What am I getting wrong here? I can get this to work using curl in bash:

```bash
cat << EOF > request.json
{
    "contents": [
        {
            "role": "user",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "Hello!"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF

API_ENDPOINT="us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
PROJECT_ID="$(gcloud config get project)"
MODEL_ID="gemini-1.0-pro-001"
LOCATION_ID="us-central1"

curl \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://${API_ENDPOINT}/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/${LOCATION_ID}/publishers/google/models/${MODEL_ID}:streamGenerateContent" -d '@request.json'
```

Comment: How are you authenticating your request? With `curl` you're using `gcloud auth print-access-token`, are you using [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials) with the Go code?

Comment: Because Google's cloud client libraries use gRPC, you can try setting `GRPC_GO_LOG_VERBOSITY_LEVEL=99` and `GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL=info` in the environment before you `go run` in order to get more comprehensive logging

Comment: @DazWilkin Yes, ADC is used with the Go code when the client is created with no specific service account. I'll try the logging you suggested as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to provide a service-specific endpoint:

```golang
// If not this, try "https://" instead of ":443"
endpoint := "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443"
opts := []option.ClientOption{
    option.WithEndpoint(endpoint),
}
client, err := aiplatform.NewPredictionClient(ctx, opts...)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("[googleGemini] ERROR! %v", err)
    return ""
}
```

[APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) documents [Method: projects.locations.publishers.models.generateContent](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.publishers.models/generateContent) and says:

> POST https://{service-endpoint}/v1/{model}:generateContent
>
> Where {service-endpoint} is one of the supported service endpoints.

I don't use Vertex AI and so am not able to easily test this. But, after running your code as-is and getting the 404 too, I then revised the code to define the endpoint and received an `RESOURCE_PROJECT_INVALID` (as expected).

Comment: The ":443" _is_ required but I tried this approach and it works!